# Querying XML Node with a where criteria

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a table with following attributes:

### [Students]

ID       Class         Data (xml)
1        Secondary     XML Data

Below is a sample xml structure that I store on the data attribute.

```
<Root>
    <Data>
        <Name>John</Name>
        <Rank>1</Rank>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <Name>Peter</Name>
        <Rank>2</Rank>
    </Data>
</Root>
```

I want to write a sql query which will give me following data from the table:

ID, Class and Rank 2 student Name
My Query is

```
Select ID,Class,Data.value('(/Root/Data/Name)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(3)')   AS [Rank 2 Student Name] 
      FROM [Students]
```

This works fine, but hardcoding the the node number to 1 is not a good idea here becuase if I add a new Data node in my xml then the data will change. And this is a possibility. So is there a way I can specify that return Name for the node where Rank value is 2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply filter in xml as follows:

```
DECLARE @Students TABLE(ID int, Class varchar(10), Data xml)

INSERT @Students VALUES (1,'A', '<Root>
    <Data>
        <Name>John</Name>
        <Rank>1</Rank>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <Name>Peter</Name>
        <Rank>2</Rank>
    </Data>
</Root>')

SELECT ID,Class,Data.value('(/Root/Data[Rank=2]/Name)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(5)') AS [Rank 2 Student Name] 
FROM @Students
```

**Result**

```
ID          Class      Rank 2 Student Name
----------- ---------- -------------------
1           A          Peter
```

---

**Edit**. If Rank contains free text, use quotes:

```
DECLARE @Students TABLE(ID int, Class varchar(10), Data xml)

INSERT @Students VALUES (1,'A', '<Root>
    <Data>
        <Name>John</Name>
        <Rank>1</Rank>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <Name>Peter</Name>
        <Rank>0:Company name</Rank>
    </Data>
</Root>')

SELECT ID,Class,Data.value('(/Root/Data[Rank="0:Company name"]/Name)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(5)') AS [Rank 2 Student Name] 
FROM @Students
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This works great for me. One last issue, above was a sample xml that I had used to demonstrated my problem. But in real life the Rank's value is
"0:State of Origin"

So when I am using 
SELECT ID,Class,Data.value('(/Root/Data[Rank=0:Company Name]/Name)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(5)') AS [Rank 2 Student Name] 
FROM @Students

its throwing an error:
Msg 9303, Level 16, State 1, Line 53
XQuery [Data.value()]: Syntax error near ':', expected ']'.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (xmlcol xml )
INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES ('<Root>
    <Data>
        <Name>John</Name>
        <Rank>1</Rank>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <Name>Peter</Name>
        <Rank>2</Rank>
    </Data>
</Root>')

SELECT *
FROM 
(
SELECT r.d.value ('(./Name/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') [Name],
       r.d.value ('(./Rank/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') [Rank]
 FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY xmlcol.nodes ('/Root/Data') R(d)
) P 
WHERE P.[Rank] = 2
```

which will output the following result:

```
Name    Rank
Peter   2
```